# Capitalization of 'LL'

Tags: ortografía, letras

When capitalizing, such as in a song title, which is the proper form of capitalization?  I have seen both:

> LLueve en Mi
>
> Llueve en Mi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only capitalize the first L.  It's a common mistake to capitalize both.  The same applies with "ch", which is capitalized "Ch". Additionally, since 2010 "elle" and "che" are no longer considered letters in Spanish. I've been told that in the past the rule was different, which is why many people capitalize both.

From RAE: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2GTxUFfOGD6Ofbt6q3

Comment: I believe that 'Ll' and 'Ch' are no longer a single letters, but even when they used to be, correct capitalization was as you say.

Comment: That's true, since 2010.